# IOS - Facebook Login Button: Unrecognized selector error

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm new to iOS and Swift, so forgive my ignorance on this subject.

I'm trying to add the Facebook Login button to my Main.storyboard.  I added a view object and set the class of the view to `FBSDKLoginButton`.  However, when I run the project in the simulator, it crashes with an unrecognized selector error.

According this, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#unrecognizedselector, I need to add `[FBSDKLoginButton class];` in my app delegate or add the -ObjC linker flag.

The question is, what is the equivalent of that code in Swift?  Or should I add the -ObjC linker flag?  Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Here is the implementation which I use*

---

```
         override func viewDidLoad() {
                super.viewDidLoad()
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

                if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
                {
                    // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
                }
                else
                {
                    let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
                    self.view.addSubview(loginView)
                    loginView.center = self.view.center
                    loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
                    loginView.delegate = self
                }

            }

    // Facebook Delegate Methods

        func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
            println("User Logged In")

            if ((error) != nil)
            {
                // Process error
            }
            else if result.isCancelled {
                // Handle cancellations
            }
            else {
                // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                // should check if specific permissions missing
                if result.grantedPermissions.contains("email")
                {
                     // Do work
                }
            }   
        }



        func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
            println("User Logged Out")
}



     func returnUserData()
        {
            let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
            graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    // Process error
                    println("Error: \(error)")
                }
                else
                {
                    println("fetched user: \(result)")
                    let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                    println("User Name is: \(userName)")
                    let userEmail : NSString = result.valueForKey("email") as! NSString
                    println("User Email is: \(userEmail)")
                }
            })
        }
```

Referred [Link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/)

Comment: This worked for me.  However, I'm still curious why adding the button directly to the storyboard and trying to use it caused that error without `[FBSDKLoginButton class];` added in the app delegate.

Answer (score 4):

i have got the same exact error.

After inspection, it's appear i need in my project : FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKLoginKit and FBSDKShareKit.

If you use cocoapods, this is the line in Podfile :

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
```

after `pod install`, add this to your bridging header .h file :

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
```

In your storyboard, define a view with class type `FBSDKLoginButton`:

[image]

Comment: since you are using pods, you do not need to #import in your bridging header, it's redundant. simply use the respective import 'FBSDKCoreKit' statements at the top the files